# How to surround occurrences of a word with quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I'm taking a basics course. The teacher asked us to create a program that finds a word of a given sentence, and prints out the sentence putting quote signs around the word in question. Now, I can get it to query for a sentence, then query for a word, and it finds it. But how do I make it replace a word, such as 'cat' with '"cat"'? I'm calling the found word 'occurrence', but I am unable to replace it with '"occurence"'. This is one of the things I've tried:

```
new_word = first.replace["(occurrence)", "(\", (occurrence), \")"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` is a *function*. To call functions in Python you need to use the syntac `functionname(…)`. Your code uses `functionname[…]`, i.e. it uses square brackets instead of parentheses.

[The parameters are also not correct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace); fixed, the code is:

```
new_word = first.replace("(occurrence)", '"(occurrence)"']
```

But if `(occurrence)` is supposed to be a *variable* containing the actual word in question, you need to change your code. For example, you can then write:

```
new_word = first.replace(occurrence, '"' + occurrence + '"']
```

(Depending on your Python version there are other, better ways of writing this — namely using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/); but the above works.)

Comment: Thank you! I tried my best but still can't get it working. What's wrong in the following? (Omg it looks horrible, I'll try to put it in single lines below.)

Comment: first = input("Give the first string (= sentence): ")

Comment: second = str(input ("Give a second string (= word or a character in the sentence): "))

Comment: occurrence = str(first.find(second))

Comment: print (first.replace('(occurrence)', '"(occurrence)"'))

Comment: @SuviSalo Does the second half of my answer not already explain this?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
str = "occurrence1 occurrence2 occurrence3 occurrence1 occurrence4"
print(str)
new_str = str.replace('occurrence1 ', "'occurrence1'")

print(new_str)
# result = 'occurrence1' occurrence2 occurrence3 'occurrence1' occurrence4
```

Comment: Thank you! Now this may be a stupid question, but how do I make the program to recognise all the words in the sentence are for example 'occurrences' (or whatever you want to call them) and organise them so that the first word is numbered 1, second 2 and so on?

Comment: Read the documentation for `replace()` and see it that answers your question. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace

Comment: @SuviSalo you should probably ask this problem as a new question so it can reach more people searching for the same problem.